# Select max id from table in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want the code to update the row "image" in my database to the name related to the picture the user chose to upload in their answer on my forum.

I want the query to take the question_id from the url and chose the highest answer id that is connected to that question_id. But the value keeps saying "NULL" it does not update.

```
  $mq = "
  UPDATE forum_answers 
     SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."'
   WHERE question_id = '$id' 
     AND a_id = '(SELECT MAX(a_id) FROM forum_answers)'
       '
   ";
   $q = mysqli_query($conn,$mq);
```

My tables

```
Table: forum_questions
rows: id, topic, detail, name, datetime, reply, view
Sample value: id=45, topic=hej, detail=haha, name=admin, datetime=25/04/17 04:01:15, view=7, reply=0


Table: forum_answers
rows: question_id, a_id, a_name, a_answer, a_datetime, image
```

The image row here wont update.

Comment: first of all u missed a space before where. Second u dont need to put selsct max query in quotes.

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code. WIsh it helps

```
 $file_name = $_FILES['file']['name'];
 $mq = "UPDATE forum_answers SET image= '$file_name' WHERE question_id='$id' 
 AND a_id=(SELECT MAX(a_id) FROM forum_answers)";
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$mq = "UPDATE forum_answers SET image = '".$_FILES['file']['name']."' WHERE question_id=$id AND a_id='(SELECT MAX(a_id) FROM forum_answers)''";
```

please try this question_id is integer type